# Use Arduino to transmit signal to a vibrating pager

Tags: arduino-uno, communication

I am an engineer at a machine shop. When a machine stops running, I want to be notified via a vibrating pager (like at restaurants). My plan is to attach the arduino board in the machine and when the machine stops (quits vibrating) I want it to trigger the vibrating pager that I have in my pocket. By what means can the arduino communicate with the vibrating pager to cause it to go off? SMS? Wifi? Bluetooth would likely be out of range. Other options?

Comment: I'd go with an internet solution (wifi), and use an online service to send a pager message. That way, in the future you could change/add other types of notification, like: SMS, e-mail, push-notification, webpage (with e.g. history information)

Comment: If the machines are CNC, add a program step at the end of the G-code to turn on a digital output to the Arduino, rather than trying to detect  “when the machine quits vibrating”

Comment: I don't write the g-code, so I'm not sure how that would work. But that sounds like a good idea. I will talk to them about that. 

Let's say the digital output is turned on..then how would I make the Arduino begin communication with the receiver? Is it just a matter of coding something along the lines of "if there is digital input, do this ..."?

Answer (score 2):

To do SMS through a GSM shield like https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield with a dataplan, and the device should be accessible anywhere you can get reception.  With a wifi shield like https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield101 you could make it work within your wifi network.

Sparkfun's sales guide at https://www.sparkfun.com/pages/wireless_guide indicates there are a few bluetooth modules that reach 100m, so if your range is less than 100m, bluetooth is a possibility.